# How far is it recommended for pipework to be from electrical sockets and switches?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, water, walls

I need to know when radiator pipes are buried into wall,how far are legal requirements stating pipes need to be from electrical sockets and switches? also what is the minimal depth  an internal building block or brick wall that is dividing a living room and a wet room has to be be if chasing in pipework for a radiator.

Answer (score 1):

There are no residential codes around pipework and electric distance other than they cannot support each other (touch).  Electric live wires are enclosed.  Pipework is enclosed.  They can be basically as close as you want them to be without them touching.